# Recovery on Linux System (initial system: Windows) (files deleted on: Windows) (Current System: Linux)

Tags: linux, windows

how to recover deleted files if,
1. initial system: Windows
2. files deleted
3. current system: Linux
Need to recover files on Linux

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed linux over the windows partition, you may be SOL (technical term).

If windows was installed on a different disk or a different partition, you could try [photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec).   This is likely in your repos as testdisk that you could fetch with yum/apt, but you may get a more recent version straight from cgsecurity.org. Run photorec, it will ask for your password so it can get root privileges. It'll ask for the partition it should work on and it will attempt to undelete a number of documents.